# Enthought Canopy missing python-config

Tags: python, macos, homebrew, enthought, python-config

Enthought Canopy ships without placing python-config in the path and a homebrew formula I'm trying to install wants to rely on the answers it gets from python-config. How should I resolve this? Some answers I've considered:

1. Is there a chance this is provided by a package I don't have installed? If yes, install it and get on with my life.
2. Roll my own python-config and yell at Enthought about it
3. Revise the homebrew formula to use a more reliable way of interrogating how to build against python

Commentary, advice, and other options would be welcome!

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to install `python-config` using `pip`. [This KB article](https://support.enthought.com/entries/23389761-Installing-external-packages-into-Canopy-Python) should help you install it.

Comment: `python-config` is not an installable package. It's [not in pypi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-config) and `pip install python-config` fails on "Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement python-config".

Comment: I think, https://pypi.python.org/pypi/config is the package that you are looking for. `pip install config` should work.

Comment: It is not, and it does not. That config package offers a facility for parsing configuration files.